# Microsoft Edge address bar no longer autofill

Tags: autocomplete, microsoft-edge, address-bar

I have loved Edge and have convinced others to use it - until 2 days ago. Out of the blue I can no longer begin typing a web site in the address bar and have it autofill. I have to type every single character.

I went into settings and found one called "Show me suggestions from my typed characters" and "Show me suggestions from history" but both are greyed out and cannot be turned on!  And they say "This setting is managed by your organization."

I have tried everything to fix this - including going back to the previous Windows.

I was going to actually uninstall Edge but found out I CANNOT DO THIS!  This is crazy. Then - when going to uninstall Edge - I saw what might be the culprit (though I have no clue - I'm not an expert). On October 7 something called "Microsoft Edge Update" was added and probably part of a Windows update and is in my list of add/remove programs, which of course as I stated above, cannot be done. I will disable Edge and stop using it if I cannot get this fixed.

What's going on?   And there were a few other weird glitches, like the most commonly used function for me is alt-tab and that was taking me weird places.  Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you please inform us which exact OS build and what version of the Edge browser you are using? I try to check on my side with MS Edge 86 version and I can see that both options are enabled. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/Rbq9vNC) I want to confirm with you whether you had applied any group policy or registry key for the Edge browser? Type `edge://policy/` in the address bar and press the enter key. See whether any policy is set.

Comment: Microsoft Edge is up to date.
Version 86.0.622.38 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: When I typed edge://policy/ it took me to a search.  Also, can I include a screen shot in my replies?  I tried to copy and paste but a screen shot wouldn't populate.  Finally, I actually found a way to add group policy editor to this Windows 10 home addition by watching a YouTube video but the changes I tried to make to fix the problem didn't work.

Comment: I suggest you type `edge://management/` in the address bar and press the enter key. See if the browser is managed by your organization.

Comment: Facing the same issue here. Version is 91.0.864.67, it is not managed and only 4 update policies are set (UpdatePolicy RollbackToTargetVersion InstallPolicy AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes). The suggestion by @user13426568 doesn't work for me since there is no such key

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me at the same time. Just delete the keys besides the default one in the following registry path:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge

Answer (score 1):

The "managed by an organization" is actually a windows wide feature. To disable or enable this, go to the settings and find `Accounts>Access Work or School`. There you can connect a work or school Microsoft account (which will manage your device) or you can select any account and "Disconnect" it. This, after a restart, will remove the "managed by an organization" notice you received.

To prevent this issue from reemerging, make sure that when you sign into any Microsoft app using a work or school account, you don't allow it to manage your device and instead select "No, Sign into this app only".

Note that, allowing an organization to manage your device can cause a lot to change down to how files are handled and how often you need to change your password.

Answer (score 0):

> Just delete the keys besides the default one in the following registry path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge

This worked for restoring the autocomplete function but my Edge still claims it's managed by an organization while it's installed on a home PC. I installed the insider beta just to install another version of Edge and it has the same issues.